# Folder only seen with unticking "Hide Protected Operating System files"?

Tags: windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive, file-attributes, hidden-file

I got an external flash drive, plug into my school's lab for use, and came back noticing all my folders have gone missing! The space shown taken is still the same

Then I played around with all Folder Options, unticked "Hide Protected Operating System files" option and voilà! All my folders are there! I suspect some virus from the lab is messing with this, but is there a way I can revert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the folder is being assigned with the system attribute

Just open command promt with admin priviledge and run

```
attrib -s folder /D
```

Comment: Ok so i tried running just attrib on the flash disk root (F:\), it doesn't show the list of folders that is assigned with system attribute. I some files with A attribute somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah i think i got it. Gotta remove the system , hidden, and read only attributes of the folder! Thanks for the help anyhow!

Comment: got `Not resetting hidden file` error, I needed to add -h as in @cloud89's anwser. I still prefer this answer as it does not reset the entire drive

Answer (score 3):

In command prompt, type this:

```
attrib  -H -S F:\\*.* /S /D /L
```

Where `F` stands for the drive name. Change it base on the drive name you want to unhide operating system files.

P.S.: All caps; it won't work if you use the lower case.

Comment: I just used lower-case letters on Windows 10, and it worked.